# What is an idiom meaning 'destroy with a hand tool' in English?

Tags: idioms, translation

I thought of "The politicians are taking a sledgehammer to England" but I don't know if it's correct to mean "The politicians are destroying England". In the source language it's used an idiom "putting the pickax" for the word destroy. It's because one uses a pickax to destroy something violently until rubble remains. What is a similar idiom in English?

Comment: Welcome! It works as a metaphor but it comes across as very extreme. If there was constant shelling of the populace by the government using actual weapons (as has happened in recent times elsewhere), then I think this would be appropriate.

Comment: Maybe, "The politicians are hammering England" or "The politicians are dismantling England piece by piece".

Comment: You are more than welcome to create your own idiom of destruction. Simply pick a hand tool and describe what it does against some innocent piece of wood or metal or stone. The sledge hammer pounds flat, the knife carves up, the axe cuts down.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly... The one who said this meant it to be extreme because in reality he took as pretext the politician's laziness, not doing enough to mean that they are destroying England, just so to oppose the actual government. In this case is the sentence "The politicians are taking a sledgehammer to England" still correct ?

Comment: I am unsure because everywhere I check idioms with a sledgehammer I find it to mean using unnecessary means to solve a minor problem... But I heard politicians in the USA today say "China took a sledgehammer to Hong Kong's democracy" which it basically means destroyed right ?

Comment: "Not doing enough" is passive. "Taking a sledgehammer" is active, so doesn't convey the passive "letting it go to ruin." But in your example China simply used the most powerful tool they could - they smashed the democracy unceremoniously.

Comment: Your metaphor is fine. It means *to destroy* or something similar. The idiom you reference above re "to solve a minor problem*" is "to use a sledgehammer to open a peanut". That's not what you're trying to say unless you consider England a peanut.

Comment: Yes I understand, it is true about the passive and the active . But in this case I have to translate it as active even though it is passive because that's the tone in which the politician said it exaggerating and that's why everyone got mad. So all I want to make sure is will an English speaker understand the meaning of what I just explained if I say: And taking as pretext the apathy of the government he said: "The politicians are taking a sledgehammer to England"?

Comment: It brings to mind the US adage "When the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail", but I doubt that that fits your intended meaning.